# How to put a support bed under an already installed bathtub?

Tags: bathroom

The bathtub was installed without a mortar bed just the  foam it comes with during transportation and seemed to be fine but after few weeks it started to squeak when taking a bath.

I have access to 3 sides of the tub and thin king of adding mortar under it but I read that expanding foam and plaster could also be an option. 
Any advices over which option is better? I'm not familiar with what kind of plaster to be used.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Careful with expanding foam; it can push the tub right off of its footings if you're not careful.

Comment: How much space is under the platform to the subfloor? Masonry cement or plaster needs a little room to work best, about 3/4" to an 1" is adequate.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this with plain Plaster of Paris, which I consider to be the best option - it's stable, but easily removed if/when the tub is replaced. I had planned to set the tub, pull it and place a pile of plaster, then reset it, but setting it the first time was such a chore that I did it from the other side of the wall instead.

It will be a bit messy, so prepare for that. With plaster you need to keep the relatively short working time in mind (it sets fairly quickly) and be sure to push enough in from the side you can access to support the opposite side. I ended up mixing several smaller batches so that I could get them placed before the plaster set, and filled in from the far side to the side I had access from with successive batches.

Comment: I like plaster also. Cleanup is easy make sure it is fully set prior to standing in the tub, I was taught to bed the tub with water in it like taking a bath volume.