# Steel bathtub making weird noises when pushing on it or standing on it?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, noise

My 20 year old steel bathtub is making weird noises when pushing on it with my hand (probably like what, maybe 10-20 pounds of pressure?) and when standing on it, the noise seems to originate around (but not directly on) the drain, does anyone know what it could be?

I'm just a simple homeowner without plumbing experience so I have no idea what could be wrong here or if anything needs to be done, or if there's any safety risk or anything?

Here are the noises: https://streamable.com/em723p

Here is a picture of the tub: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o82P.jpg

[image]

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this.

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/74710/18078  and https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/36914/18078

Comment: and https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/105146/18078

Comment: So it sounds like it didn't have a proper base or it didn't have a base or the base wore out after 20 years I guess. Is there any problems with leaving it the way it is or is it fine? I'd rather leave it alone if there aren't any safety or other concerns the way it is.

Comment: Movement and flexing may cause the finish to crack, followed by rust, followed by either replacing the tub or trying to get a new coat of paint-like-substance to stick (or paying more than the price of a new tub for a very costly but cheaply made bathtub liner from one of those "too good to be true" bathtub remodeling places. They are ...not true, and not that good. The one I talked to was about 5 times the cost of a new tub, and had all sorts of conditions favorable to them in the paperwork *i.e., if we refit your tub and the pipes leak due to our work, not our problem...*)

Comment: If it's moving around the drain, that could also cause a drain pipe failure or leak.

Comment: If it's moving with only 10 kg pressure, you might check if water seepage has led to *extensive* rot under the tub. Filling the tub with water might lead to its descent into the room below.

Comment: If the subfloor was actually rotted, wouldn't the joists still be fine holding it up, so the tub wouldn't be able to go through the floor? Or were you overexagurating? Isn't it like, pretty rare for a tub to go through the floor?

Comment: Joists can rot as well, if that's what's going on here. They are not immune to rot by reason of being joists...

Comment: If there were rot bad enough to affect the joists wouldn't there be any signs of water damage like the ceiling being stained? I'm not sure I've even used this shower enough for there to be any rot, I used the master bathroom shower for years and only started using this shower the past month or so and not even super often at that. How would I know if there's rot vs the base layer underneath the tub just wearing out after being 20 years old?

Comment: Another reason I think it's probably not leaking is just today I looked at the drywall directly underneat the tub, and it's perfect, bone-dry looks brand new no stains or anything even though this house is actually like 20 years old lol